# Xamarin Forms Maps Pin Callout

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin) to create a custom `MapRenderer` for iOS in my Xamarin.Forms PCL project, which in itself works fine. However, I'm desperately looking for a way to react on tap/click events on a `Pin`'s callout (i.e. the info flag that pops up when you tap on a `Pin` itself). I know that there's a `OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped` on the iOS level, but is there a way to react on callout-taps/clicks on PCL level? Only thing I could find is the `Pin.Clicked` event.

```
pin.Clicked += async(sender, e) => {
    await DisplayAlert("Test", "Test", "test");
};
```

Is there a similar event for the callout (don't know what it's called on Android, sorry), which opens up when you click on a pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for everybody reading this having the same idea/problem:

The event `Pin.Clicked` will be fired whenever the user clicks on the `Pin`'s label and **NOT** on the `Pin` itself!

Answer (score 1):

in Android ,`CustomMapRenderer` class implements the `GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter` interface which have `GetInfoWindow` and `GetInfoContents` methods to customize the info window ,and there is an event `OnInfoWindowClick`, when the user clicks on the info window,this method opens a web browser and navigates to the address stored in the `Url` property of the retrieved `CustomPin` instance for the `Marker`.
you could refer to :[Custom Map Pin on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-android)

Comment: The thing is: I'd like to have that event on PCL level (i.e. on the common/shared code), not iOS or Android.

Comment: Haha I'm such an idiot, the `Pin.Clicked`event does exactly what I want, which admittedly is a little unintuitive, because I thought it would fire on pin taps rather than pin-label-taps.